# Select field having more than 1 associated fields

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Below is sample VIEW_TEST table from which I want to select deviceId’s which are associated with more than 1 tracks. Eg. 100th device is associated with FirstTrack as well as SecondTrack, so it should be selected

[image: Sample Table]

I have tried lot of things but not able to get answer for it. Following is the query that I tried but it is not returning anything

```
select deviceid
from ( SELECT  distinct deviceid, trackid , count (distinct deviceid) over (partition by trackid) as cnt 
    FROM VIEW_TEST) t
    where cnt > 0;
```

When I executed below internal query,

```
SELECT  distinct deviceid, trackid , count (distinct deviceid) over (partition by trackid) as cnt 
    FROM VIEW_TEST
```

It gives me following output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use window function you can do instead :

```
select t.*
from VIEW_TEST t
where exists (select 1 from VIEW_TEST t1 where t1.deviceid = t.deviceid and t1.trackid <> t.trackid);
```

You can also use `group by` clause :

```
select deviceid
from VIEW_TEST t
group by deviceid
having min(trackid) <> max(trackid);
```

However, `COUNT(DISTINCT trackid)` would also help :

```
select deviceid
from VIEW_TEST t
group by deviceid
having count(distinct trackid) > 1;
```

Comment: **Thank you so much Yogesh.** It worked like a charm.